# ClassLoader on virtual machine

Tags: java, swt, classloader

I have source code:

```
private Image getImage(String path, ClassLoader loader) {
    InputStream image = null;
    try {
        image = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
        return new Image(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(), image);
    } finally {
        if (image != null) {
            try {
                image.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                //OK
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my computer this code works perfect. But, on virtual machine line:

```
loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

always returns null. Why?

EDIT:

Path is a relative path. For example: icons/tools/device.png.
Application which I develop contains more than ten projects. I use Eclipse IDE. All projects have structure:

- com.pkg.name - folder with classes icons
- folder with icons and others files

Jar files have this structure too.

On my computer applications works perfect. On virtual machine (Windows Server(64-bit)) application can't loads images from Jar file.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what VM you're talking about? I though JVM at first glance, but that might be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Of course. Virtual machine means - a 64-bit Windows Server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine.

Comment: Another question - is is a standard java app, OSGI or even RCP based? If it's OSGi or RCP, then the problem may be solved by double checking the manifests and their export/import sections.

Comment: This is RCP application based on uDig. Andreas_D:"the problem may be solved by double checking the manifests and their export/import sections" - It is OK. This is working on my computer.

Comment: mykhaylo - you should have given **that** info earlier - classloading in OSGi is much more complicated then in non-OSGi applications.

Comment: I didn't know that it is so important. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If path is a relative path, then it should work, as long as the image resource has been copied along with the class files (as Itay already mentioned) and the folder or jar that contains the image resource is on the classpath (do you use CLASSPATH or -cp to specify the classpath? If you rely on CLASSPATH, make sure, the this environment variable is properly set for the user that executes the application)

If it is an absolute path, double check if it is valid on the target VM.

so basically, for a folder structure like

```
./classes
./images
./libs
```

the command `java -cp classes;images;libs/* my.app.Application` should work (java 1.6 - in older versions the wildcard is not allowed), assuming a path value like `images/myImage.jpg`.

Just another thought, the classpath delimter is `;` on Windows and `:` on unix. That might be a problem if you prepared the app on a unix-type environment.

**Edit**

Do you read the image from the same library as you actual classfile? Then please give this a try:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)
```

**Edit**

OK, it's OSGi. So there are some more reasons why the application works from inside the eclipse IDE but not when deployed as a RCP application. I think it has nothing to do with the target environment.

In OSGi every bundle has it's own classloader and a class from bundle1 will not be able to see classes from bundle2 unless the packages are properly exported. This is true for resources as well. I guess that the image is stored in a different bundle. I don't know which classloader is passed to the getImage method, but that classloader definitely can't see the resource file.

It might work inside eclipse, especially if you add the projects to each others build paths.

After you've built the product, you said it fails (partially) on the VM but does the same product show the image on the local machine (outside eclipse)?

Comment: I do not use CLASSPATH. CLASSPATH is required by ClassLoder?

Comment: I tested this method(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)). Unfortunately, returns always null.

Comment: "Does the same product show the image on the local machine (outside eclipse)?" - No! You were right! I did a lot of tests. Now everything works. I used the class loader from my class that inherits from UDIGApplication. I load images in the "init" method of this class. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supplying enough details but here is my guess:

When you copy the code to the location where it will run by the the other (virtual) machine you copy only the *.class files. You need to copy other resources (in particular image files) and place them along with the *.class files so that the classloder can retrieve them.

When you develop code with Eclipse (or other IDEs), Eclipse takes care of copying your resources from the src/ directory to the bin/ directory.

Comment: I am sure that all files exist on the virtual machine. I always export my source code to the Jar file. Jar contains all resource files.